# Calculate time difference of rows which match condition in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, window-functions

I have a PostgreSQL table where I need to calculate the time interval in which a name is in the state 1. A name can be in this state multiple times and I need the time of each individual interval. I am using a temp table at the moment in which I save the start and endpoints of an interval and then calculate the time difference of it. But I don't like this solution and think there must be a better way of doing it. I hope to find some SQL Pros out here who can show me some magical and easy solution.

Here is how the table looks like:

```
|name   |state |time                      |
|-------|------|--------------------------|
|one    | 1    |'2020-11-11 01:00:02.5+01'| (start of first interval)
|one    | 1    |'2020-11-11 01:00:04.5+01'| (end of first interval) = 2 seconds
|one    | 0    |'2020-11-11 01:00:05.0+01'|
|one    | 0    |'2020-11-11 01:00:05.5+01'|
|one    | 1    |'2020-11-11 01:00:10.5+01'| (start of second interval)
|one    | 1    |'2020-11-11 01:00:11.5+01'| 
|one    | 1    |'2020-11-11 01:00:12.5+01'| (end of second interval) = 2 seconds
|two    | 0    |'2020-11-11 01:00:13.0+01'|
|two    | 0    |'2020-11-11 01:00:14.5+01'|
|two    | 1    |'2020-11-11 01:00:15.0+01'| (start of third interval)
|two    | 1    |'2020-11-11 01:00:15.5+01'| (end of third interval) = 0.5 seconds
|two    | 0    |'2020-11-11 01:00:16.5+01'|
```

SQL script for the sample table:

```
CREATE TABLE intervals(
    name char(10),
    state integer,
    time timestamptz
);

INSERT INTO intervals(name, state, time) VALUES
    ('one', 1, '2020-11-11 01:00:02.5+01'),
    ('one', 1, '2020-11-11 01:00:04.5+01'),
    ('one', 0, '2020-11-11 01:00:05.0+01'),
    ('one', 0, '2020-11-11 01:00:05.5+01'),
    ('one', 1, '2020-11-11 01:00:10.5+01'),
    ('one', 1, '2020-11-11 01:00:11.5+01'),
    ('one', 1, '2020-11-11 01:00:12.5+01'),
    ('two', 0, '2020-11-11 01:00:13.0+01'),
    ('two', 0, '2020-11-11 01:00:14.5+01'),
    ('two', 1, '2020-11-11 01:00:15.0+01'),
    ('two', 1, '2020-11-11 01:00:15.5+01'),
    ('two', 0, '2020-11-11 01:00:16.5+01');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.  In this case, the difference of row numbers should do what you want:

```
select name, min(time), max(time),
       max(time) - min(time) as duration
from (select i.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name order by time) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by name, state order by time) as seqnum_2
      from intervals i
     ) i
where state = 1
group by name, (seqnum - seqnum_2), state;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1628059218a0062e7272f58edb2656e4) is a db<>fiddle.

The logic on the difference of row numbers is a little tricky to explain.  If you run the subquery, you will see how the difference of row numbers on rows with the same name and adjacent values of `state` is constant.  The aggregation just aggregates by the difference, which is constant for them.

Comment: Thank you very much! This solution is great and so neat. But I don't understand it completely. How are the seqnum and seqnum_2 working in combination with the min() and max()?